# How to use @EnableTransactionManagement in combination with a StaticMethodMatcherPointcutAdvisor

Tags: java, spring, transactions, aop

Given the following service:

```
public interface MyService {
    void method();
}
```

And it's implementation:

```
@Service
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {

    @Transactional
    @CustomAnnotation
    @Override
    public void method() {
        ...
    }
}
```

I would like to use a `StaticMethodMatcherPointcutAdvisor` in the following manner:

```
public class MyPointcutAdvisor extends StaticMethodMatcherPointcutAdvisor {
   ...

    @Override       
    public boolean matches(Method method, Class targetClass) {
       Method m = method;
       if(annotationPresent(method)) {
           return true;
       }
       Class<?> userClass = ClassUtils.getUserClass(targetClass);
       Method specificMethod = ClassUtils.getMostSpecificMethod(method, userClass);
       specificMethod = BridgeMethodResolver.findBridgedMethod(specificMethod);
       if(annotationPresent(specificMethod )) {
           return true;
       }
       return false;
    }
    ...
}
```

The problem is that Spring uses an `InfrastructureAdvisorAutoProxyCreator` to create a Proxy of that class, whereas the `DefaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator` would create the proxy for the `MyPointcutAdvisor`, but the `MyPointcutAdvisor` is only given the proxy as `targetClass` parameter. Thus, the PointcutAdvisor cannot find the annotation and therefore does not match.

For completion this is my Configuration-class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class MyConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public DefaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator defaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator() {
        return new DefaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator();
    }

    @Bean
    public MyPointcutAdvisor myPointcutAdvisor() {
        return new MyPointcutAdvisor();
    } 
    ...
}
```

**My question is: Is there a way to use `@EnableTransactionManagement` in combination with a `StaticMethodMatcherPointcutAdvisor` ?**

Workarounds:

- Put `@CustomAnnotation` into the service interface: I want to have clean interfaces.
- Add `@Role(BeanDefinition.ROLE_INFRASTRUCTURE)` to `MyPointCutAdvisor` bean configuration, thus, the `InfrastructureAdvisorAutoProxyCreator` will create the proxy. This seems like the wrong way, since this bean is not infrastructure
- Copy the beans from `ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration`, remove `@EnableTransactionManagement` and remove `@Role(BeanDefinition.ROLE_INFRASTRUCTURE)`, thus the `DefaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator` will create the proxy, which is my current workaround and results in the following configuration:

  ```
  @Configuration
  public class MyWorkaroundConfiguration {
      @Bean
      public DefaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator defaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator() {
          return new DefaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator();
      }

      @Bean
      public MyPointcutAdvisor myPointcutAdvisor() {
          return new MyPointcutAdvisor();
      }

      @Bean
      public TransactionAttributeSource transactionAttributeSource() {
          return new AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource();
      }

      @Bean(name = TransactionManagementConfigUtils.TRANSACTION_ADVISOR_BEAN_NAME)
      public BeanFactoryTransactionAttributeSourceAdvisor transactionAdvisor(
              TransactionInterceptor transactionInterceptor) {
          BeanFactoryTransactionAttributeSourceAdvisor advisor =
              new BeanFactoryTransactionAttributeSourceAdvisor();
          advisor.setTransactionAttributeSource(transactionAttributeSource());
          advisor.setAdvice(transactionInterceptor);
          return advisor;
      }

      @Bean
      public TransactionInterceptor transactionInterceptor(
              PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) {
          TransactionInterceptor interceptor = new TransactionInterceptor();
          interceptor.setTransactionAttributeSource(transactionAttributeSource());
          interceptor.setTransactionManager(transactionManager);
          return interceptor;
      } 
      ...
  }
  ```

Comment: Rewrite your `StaticMethodMatcherPointcutAdvisor` extension to an `@Aspect` and combine with `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` then you shouldn't need those work arounds. Another thing you could try is to keep this and add the `@Role` annotation to yuor `@Bean` method and make it an infrastructure bean.

Comment: I added the @Role workaround to my list. I know this is possible with AspectJ proxies but I want to know whether there is a way without AspectJ with normal Jdk-proxies

Comment: The fact that you use AspectJ has nothing to do with the use of JDK proxies or not... Even when using an `@Aspect` you can still perfectly use JDK Dynamic Proxies to have the `@Aspect` applied. It is just another way of expression your concerns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using @EnableAspectJAutoProxy instead of the DefaultAutoProxyCreator works for me.

```
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class MyConfiguration {

}
```

This also allows using @Aspect like M. Deinum suggested.